# Ordering of MATLAB operator

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to understand a MATLAB code for reserach but seem to be stuck in a basic question regarding the order of the transpose operator and ml divide operator. (please see the code below)

```
C = randi([0 ,1], [3,3])
D = randi([0 ,1], [3,3])

disp("C-(D')*(C\D')")
disp(C-(D')*(C\D'))
```

(you may need to run this multiple times until the inverse exists)

Because the transpose operator is computed before the `\` operator, it seems taht `C\D'` should be equal to finding the `x` s.t. `C=(D')*x`... However, when I subsrtitute `x` as `C\D'` and display `C-(D')*x`, I don't get a zero... could anyone give me a reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C = [0,0,1;0,1,0;1,0,1];
D = [1,1,0;1,0,1;1,0,0];
%% rule
% "A \ B" equal to "inv(A) * B"
% "B / A" equal to "B * inv(A)"
%% mine
X = C / D'; % X = C * inv(D')
C - X * D'  % C - (C * inv(D')) * D' = C - C * (inv(D') * D') = 0
%% yours
Y = C \ D'; % Y = inv(C) * D'
C - D'* Y   % C - D' * (inv(C) * D') ≠ 0
```

Comment: Thank you! :) It's my first time doing MATLAB so it was a bit confusing but you sorted it out for me :)